# delete rows of and 2D array with a condition refering to a different array in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have two numpy arrays:

```py
a = np.array([12, 13, 10])
b = np.array([[22, 123], [10, 142], [23, 232], [42, 122], [12, 239]])
```

I want to delete rows in `b` if the first element is not in `a`. Something like:

```py
c = np.delete(b, np.where(a not in b[:, 0]))
```

`print(c)` gives:

```py
[ 22 123  10 142  23 232  42 122  12 239]
```

which doesn't delete an element: `c` should look like

```
c = [[10, 142],
     [12, 239]]
```

Comment: what does `a not in b[:,0]` produce?  And after the `np.where`?  You need to understand, and know, what each step in the expression is doing.  Also review what `np.delete` expects.

Comment: Those are not numpy arrays...

Answer (score 1):

Your input:

```py
import numpy as np

a=[12,13,10]
b=[[22, 123],[10,142],[23,232],[42,122],[12,239]]
a, b = np.array(a), np.array(b)

c = b[np.isin(b[:, 0], a)]
```

Output:

```py
array([[ 10, 142],
       [ 12, 239]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the rows in `b` whose first elements are not in `a`. `np.isin` returns an array of that masks the first input. It also provides an argument `invert`, to speed up the inversion that you want:

```
mask = np.isin(b[:, 0], a, invert=True)
```

You can use this mask in `np.delete` directly:

```
c = np.delete(b, mask, axis=0)
```

Alternatively, you can convert it to indices using `np.flatnonzero`:

```
index = np.flatnonzero(mask)
result = np.delete(b, index, axis=0)
```

Furthermore, you don't need to use `np.delete` at all, since indexing with the non-inverted mask will drop the undesired rows:

```
result = b[np.isin(b[:, 0], a)]
```